# Various ways of creating Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory-management

Are these methods of creating an empty Ruby Hash different? If so how?

```
myHash = Hash.new

myHash = {}
```

I'd just like a solid understanding of memory management in Ruby.

Comment: How many hash objects are created in: 
    (1..10).each do 
      myHash = {}
    end

Comment: No they're the same; both yield an empty hash. If you're really interested in memory management, you might be better off asking a question about a particular ruby interpreter implementation. Object creation and memory management are somewhat orthogonal concepts in Ruby  ; Can I infer that if you're asking this question, the memory footprint of a ruby application is of particular concern to you?

Comment: @ChrisMowforth ok I'll look into my interpreter. I'm just learning Ruby and since I'm coming from a c/c++/Obj-c background I'm curious about memory management.

Comment: @Ramon I'd like to print `myHash.object_id` in the `do` loop. How can I do this?

Comment: @MrMusic, "I'm just learning Ruby and since I'm coming from a c/c++/Obj-c background I'm curious about memory management." In general, we don't really care in Ruby, only when we've run into problems and managed to consume all available memory or reduce a machine to a crawl do we sit up and take notice. That probably sounds a bit cavalier, coming from a C/C++ world, but it's the beauty of a scripting language. That said, it's good to pay attention to intelligent use of hashes and arrays, and to not try to read huge files or database requests into RAM. Iteration is our friend. Welcome to Ruby!

Comment: @theTinMan you make Ruby sound pretty awesome. I'm excited to learn a technology that's substantially different from c/c++ etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways you can create a Hash object in Ruby, though the end result is the same sort of object:

```
hash = { }
hash = Hash.new
hash = Hash[]
hash = some_object.to_h
hash = YAML.load("--- {}\n\n")
```

As far as memory considerations go, an empty Hash is significantly smaller than one with even a singular value in it. Arrays tend to be smaller than Hashes at small sizes, but will be more efficient at larger scales.

In practice, though, the important thing to remember in Ruby is that every time you create an object it *costs* you something, even if it's only an infinitesimal amount. These little hits add up if you're needlessly creating billions of objects.

Generally you should avoid creating structures that will not be used, and instead create them on demand if that wouldn't complicate things needlessly. For example, a typical pattern is:

```
def cache
  @cache ||= { }
end
```

Until this method is called, the cache Hash is never defined. The memory savings in this instance is nearly insignificant, but if that was loading a large configuration file or importing several hundred MB of data from a database you can imagine the savings would be significant in those instances where that data is not exercised.

Answer (score 2):

The two methods are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned above, the two are operationally equivalent. If you're referring to the standard MRI / YARV; perhaps this thread would help: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215163#new.

Answer (score 0):

With the Hash.new syntax you can specify what to do when some key is absent in the hash (the [default behaviour](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new)). With the the {} syntax it takes another step.

```
my_hash = Hash[]
```

is another way of creating an array; the [] methods takes an even number of arguments.

```
my_hash = Hash[:a, 1, :b, 2]
```

This has nothing to do with memory management.